# Sonarcloud rule - Having executables not owned by root is security-sensitive

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

Inside dockerfile for node application (pm2 process)

`COPY --chown=node:node --from=builder-nest /var/www/html/ /var/www/html/`

it gives an error in sonar lint: **Having executables not owned by root is security-sensitive**

they suggest `COPY --chown=root:root --chmod=644 src.py dst.py`

using root with chmod

I want to ask if this approach is better than setting node owner for dist ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to chown files to your container user.

If you have a typical Dockerfile setup like

```bash
FROM node:something
# USER root, implicitly
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY ./ ./

USER node
CMD node ./index.js
```

then your application source code will be owned by `root`, and generally world-readable but not world-writable.  That means your application can't overwrite its own source or libraries or static assets, whether intentionally or by accident.  That's generally good security practice, and the direction Sonarlint is steering you towards.

So, don't `chown` your application source to your container's non-root user.  Don't set directories to mode 0777.  If your application really absolutely can't avoid having local state, make sure it's isolated to a single directory (not your application root directory), and make that single directory only owned by the non-root user.

```bash
# if absolutely needed
RUN mkdir data && chown node data
```